# php cli popen() include file once?

Tags: php

I am doing this in my main file lets say `index.php`

```
$handle = popen("php -q nah.php -p=". escapeshellarg($part) . " 2>&1", "r");
while (!feof($handle))
{
    $read = fread($handle, 2096);
    echo $read;
}
pclose($handle);
```

What i want is that i dont include a file containing a number of classes in the `nah.php` and not including it in the nah.php because the nah.php gets provoked using a while loop so if i include in it in `nah.php` it will slow down a bit.

Is it possible ?

Comment: Could you please rephrase your question?

Comment: @wonk0 I want to include a file in the main file and not in the file provoked by the file as.

Comment: @kritya: define _'a bit'_ because if it's just class/function files, especially when autoloaded, I think you're talking to much effort for a couple of milliseconds.

Comment: Just to be sure, you are trying to include a class just once but have it available in all the different php processes you open?

Comment: @gnur yesh :D something like that :D

Answer (score 0):

If you are saying that, while PHP is in CLI mode, you don't want to include files that would otherwise be included by `nah.php`, do:

```
if (php_sapi_name() !== 'cli')
{
  // include files here
}
```

Otherwise... just don't include the files... ?

Comment: No No. i want to include all the files ONLY once and not in the files which have been provoked by the popen

Answer (score 0):

Or go for `pcntl_fork` for this one (if this is in CLI, don't do it in a webserver for a variety of reasons). You'll only have to load all class/function definitions once (but don't open resources yet, for instance, a database connection should be opened in the child). Getting the data back is then a little bit more work, but not terribly difficult. I don't think you'll get any significant speed gain however...